# How to create a (javax.bluetooth.)RemoteDevice / connect with mac-address

Tags: java, bluetooth, google-glass, mac-address

I need a connection from java to an UNVISIBLE paired android (google glass),
therefore I need to hard-code connect to the glass into java code.

It would be pretty easy if I could create a RemoteDevice with the mac address.

Here is the API for this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/bluetooth/jsr082/javax/bluetooth/RemoteDevice.html

But the constructor is PROTECTED, so how can I solve it?

(I need it in java, not in android, the android way does not work)